# Symfony Dependency Injection via XML

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I'm using the component (version 2.7) not the symfony framework.

I'm using PHP to inject and it is OK but I decided to use XML. I don't know how to load XML stored services into ContainerBuilder object,

I'm using the component this way:

```
$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$container->setDefinition('Crypt', new Definition('MiladRahimi\PHPCrypt\Crypt'));
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Thank you answered below, but Another one, What I should add to XML to be lazy load?

Comment: If you have another question, you must start a new thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component is [nicely documented](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/index.html). You'll find everything you need in the official docs.

Specifically, read on [Setting up the Container with Configuration Files](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html#setting-up-the-container-with-configuration-files) and [Compiling the container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html). Make sure you [dump the container for better performance](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#dumping-the-configuration-for-performance).

Here's an example of loading an xml file, taken from the documentation:

```php
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader;

$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__));
$loader->load('services.xml');
```

Comment: Another one, What I should add to XML to be lazy load?